# Removing specified characters from a string - Efficient methods (time and space complexity)

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

Here is the problem: Remove specified characters from a given string.

```
Input: The string is "Hello World!" and characters to be deleted are "lor"
Output: "He Wd!"
```

Solving this involves two sub-parts:

1. Determining if the given character is to be deleted
2. If so, then deleting the character

To solve the first part, I am reading the characters to be deleted into a `std::unordered_map`, i.e. I parse the string "lor" and insert each character into the hashmap. Later, when I am parsing the main string, I will look into this hashmap with each character as the key and if the returned value is non-zero, then I delete the character from the string.

**Question 1:** Is this the best approach?

**Question 2:** Which would be better for this problem? `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`? Since I am not interested in ordering, I used an `unordered_map`. But is there a higher overhead for creating the hash table? What to do in such situations? Use a `map` (balanced tree) or a `unordered_map` (hash table)?

Now coming to the next part, i.e. deleting the characters from the string. One approach is to delete the character and shift the data from that point on, back by one position. In the worst case, where we have to delete all the characters, this would take O(n^2).

The second approach would be to copy only the required characters to another buffer. This would involve allocating enough memory to hold the original string and copy over character by character leaving out the ones that are to be deleted. Although this requires additional memory, this would be a O(n) operation.

The third approach, would be to start reading and writing from the 0th position, increment the source pointer when every time I read and increment the destination pointer only when I write. Since source pointer will always be same or ahead of destination pointer, I can write over the same buffer. This saves memory and is also an O(n) operation. I am doing the same and calling `resize` in the end to remove the additional unnecessary characters?

Here is the function I have written:

```
// str contains the string (Hello World!)
// chars contains the characters to be deleted (lor)
void remove_chars(string& str, const string& chars)
{
    unordered_map<char, int> chars_map;

    for(string::size_type i = 0; i < chars.size(); ++i)
        chars_map[chars[i]] = 1;

    string::size_type i = 0; // source
    string::size_type j = 0; // destination
    while(i < str.size())
    {
        if(chars_map[str[i]] != 0)
            ++i;
        else
        {
            str[j] = str[i];
            ++i;
            ++j;
        }
    }

    str.resize(j);
}
```

**Question 3:** What are the different ways by which I can improve this function. Or is this best we can do?

Thanks!

Comment: Please ask only one question per question.

Comment: ¤ **Q1** and  **Q2**: note that `CHAR_BIT` = 8 on most implementations, and is in practice at worst 16 bits. So for efficiency and with a single `char` per character, just use an array for the lookup. You might consider a `std::bitset` or `std::vector<bool>`. **Q3**: For usability make a function-like wrapper. For coding clarity forget about fretting about `string::size_type`. Just use `int`, or `ptrdiff_t`. Cheers,

Comment: This q. might possibly better be asked at the code review site.

Comment: As fas as I can see, the only value you ever map to is 1. Therefore why use an `unordered_map`, not an `unordered_set`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're studying algorithms, and not interested in library solutions:

Hash tables are most valuable when the number of possible keys is large, but you only need to store a few of them.  Your hash table would make sense if you were deleting specific 32-bit integers from digit sequences.  But with ASCII characters, it's overkill.

Just make an array of 256 bools and set a flag for the characters you want to delete.  It only uses one table lookup instruction per input character.  Hash map involves at least a few more instructions to compute the hash function.  Space-wise, they are probably no more compact once you add up all the auxiliary data.

```
void remove_chars(string& str, const string& chars)
{
    // set up the look-up table
    std::vector<bool> discard(256, false);
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.size(); ++i)
    {
        discard[chars[i]] = true;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < str.size(); ++j)
    {
        if (discard[str[j]])
        {
            // do something, depending on your storage choice
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding your storage choices: Choose between options 2 and 3 depending on whether you need to preserve the input data or not.  3 is obviously most efficient, but you don't always want an in-place procedure.

Comment: I would use `bitset<256>`, but still a great answer. Slightly more efficient than `strspn` and `strcspn` as you initialize the table only once.

Comment: `bitset` is optimized for space.  It packs the bits into a smaller space at the expense of extra bit-mask operations to store and retrieve bits.  It would be useful for a large bitset but definitely slower than `vector<bool>`.  (Not being confrontational, just explaining my choice)

Comment: I believe `vector<bool>` is still specialized to be equivalent to `bitset` underneath. `array<bool, 256>` would be the best of both worlds: no dynamic allocations and unpacked size.

Comment: @japreiss Thanks for the answer. From what I understand, char is not required to be unsigned. It can also have values between -128 to +127, depending on the platform. If that is the case, wouldn't `discard[chars[i]]` cause a memory fault?

Comment: @Vinay True, I hadn't thought of that.  Since the actual numeric values don't matter, you could always `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char>`.  That seems a little hacky but it would work.  Also you could replace `256` with `1 << (sizeof(unsigned char) - 1)` for less implementation dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Good job, now learn about the standard library algorithms and boost:

```
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), boost::is_any_of("lor")), str.end());
```

Comment: Thanks. That's awesome. I did not know about boost:is_any_of.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) solution with many advantages:

```
void remove_chars (char *dest, const char *src, const char *excludes)
{
    do {
        if (!strchr (excludes, *src))
            *dest++ = *src;
    } while (*src++);
    *dest = '\000';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ping pong between `strcspn` and `strspn` to avoid the need for a hash table:

```
void remove_chars(
    const char *input, 
    char *output, 
    const char *characters)
{
    const char *next_input= input;
    char *next_output= output;

    while (*next_input!='\0')
    {
        int copy_length= strspn(next_input, characters);
        memcpy(next_output, next_input, copy_length);

        next_output+= copy_length;

        next_input+= copy_length;
        next_input+= strcspn(next_input, characters);
    }
}
```