# What is the best way to remove punctuations and white spaces in c++?

Tags: c++, string

In order to remove white spaces and punctuations from a given string. Using a regular expression match seems an approach, but will it be efficient to use a bool array[256] and set those values of punctuations and spaces to be true. Also since this will be called multiple times it is better to use it as a static array, but how do I set the values for punctions and space as true in the char array? Like write a separate static method to do that?

Comment: What about [`ispunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct) and [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace)?

Comment: Is your end goal to have a string with no white space and punctuation, or a array that marks the places of the white space and punctuation characters?

Comment: The best approach is to attempting something yourself, then consult Google if you're stuck.

Comment: How does setting anything to `true` "remove white spaces and punctuations"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing specified characters from a string - Efficient methods (time and space complexity)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843007/removing-specified-characters-from-a-string-efficient-methods-time-and-space)

Comment: Is there an echo in here?

Comment: does ispunct and isspace take O(1) time?

Answer (score 3):

If you've got C++11, you can do this easily with a lambda.

```
s.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        s.begin(), s.end(),
        []( unsigned char ch ) { return isspace( ch ) || ispunct( ch ); } ),
    s.end() );
```

This uses the current global locale.

Without C++11, you'll have to define a functional object
(reusable if you're doing this a lot):

```
struct IsSpaceOrPunct
{
    bool operator()( unsigned char ch ) const
    {
        return isspace( ch ) || ispunct( ch );
    }
};
```

And use an instance of this in place of the lambda in the C++
expression.

These both use the `is...` functions in `<ctype.h>` (which is
why they operate on `unsigned char`—invoking these
functions with a `char` is undefined behavior).

A more general solution would be more along the lines of:

```
template <std::ctype_base::mask m>
class Is
{
    std::locale l;  //  To ensure lifetime of the following...
    std::ctype<char> const* ctype;
public:
    Is( std::locale const& l = std::locale() )
        : l( l )
        , ctype( &std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>( l ) )
    {
    }
    bool operator()( char ch ) const
    {
        return is( m, ch );
    }
};

typedef Is<std::ctype_base::space | std::ctype_base::punct> IsSpaceOrPunct;
```

For simple, one of applications, this is overkill (unless you
really do need to support the varying locales), but if you do
any significant amount of text handling, you'll definitely want
to have it.  Because of the template, you can get all sorts of
predicates for almost no work, just another typedef.

Comment: The version of `isspace` and `ispunct` in `<ctype>` operates on `int`, not `unsigned char`.

Comment: @ZacHowland And?  There's an implicit conversion from `unsigned char` to `int`.  And unlike the case of `char` to `int`, this conversion is guaranteed to result in a value of the `int` which can be legally passed to the functions in `<ctype.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

The two answers provided will work, but an approach that does not require casting a function pointer:

```
std::string text = "some text, here and there.  goes up; goes down";
std::string result;
std::remove_copy_if(text.begin(), text.end(), std::back_inserter(result), [](char c)
{
    std::locale loc;
    return std::ispunct(c, loc) || std::isspace(c, loc);
});
```

Comment: Heh, practically reuses your remove_copy_if from the erase/remove question earlier today :-)

Comment: And it has the usual undefined behavior.  You cannot call the single parameter form of `ispunct` with a `char` (nor a `char` converted to `int`, since this changes absolutely nothing).

Comment: @JamesKanze `char` is implicitly convertible to an `int`, so it is not UB.  But there is an alternative method using the newer `ispunct` in `<locale>`, which does the same thing.

Comment: @ZacHowland `ispunct` doesn't work with just any `int`; there is a precondition that the `int` be in the range `[0...UCHAR_MAX]` (or that it be `EOF`).  The implicit conversion of `char` to `int` will result in values outside of this range.

Comment: @ZacHowland The newer versions (which operate on `char`, and not `int`) are the way to go, but they require a `locale`, and are significantly slower, due to the necessity of extracting the `ctype` facet from the locale.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`std::remove_copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy) with [`std::ispunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct)

```
string text ="some text with punctuations",result;
std::remove_copy_if(text.begin(), text.end(),            
                        std::back_inserter(result), //Store output           
                        std::ptr_fun<int, int>(&std::ispunct)  
                       );
```

Comment: Correct approach, but still undefined behavior (and not the function he wanted).

Comment: Because the C standard says so (and C++ inherits `ispunct` from C).  All of the functions in `<ctype.h>` have a precondition that the input must be in the range `[0...UCHAR_MAX]` (or be `EOF`).  The implicit (or explicit) conversion of `char` to `int` results in a value in the range `[CHAR_MIN...CHAR_MAX]`.  On most implementations, `CHAR_MIN` is negative.

Comment: @JamesKanze Unless the text in question is well outside of the ASCII ranges, the bounds issue will never come up.  All of the ASCII characters below 127.

Comment: @ZacHowland Which means what?  That you have to verify before hand that all of the characters are in a legal range?  That you only work with a limited subset of the characters the system supports?  (In the earliest Unix, the requirement was that the `int` be in the range `[0...127]`, and there was a separate function, `isascii`, which tested this.  If you go this route, you'd have to implement this function, and use it systematically before any of the others.  And you'd be going back 30 years in time.)